# A transfer at an airport where you don't have admission into a country

Tags: visas, transit, australia, new-zealand, visa-bans

I have a 3-year ban in Australia, with 1.5 years left. The reason: I thought my student visa expired in July but it expired in June, so I overstayed my visa for 1 month. I am going to New Zealand on a working holiday visa and I'm transferring from Brisbane (AUS) to NZ. Will I have any complications or can I go to NZ with no worries?

Comment: What's your nationality? Would you normally require a visa to transit in Australia?

Comment: How long is your stay in Brisbane?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you *may* be okay, depending on the airport through which you are flying.

[Australia's rules are listed here](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/lega/lega/form/immi-faqs/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-through-australia) and, to summarize them:

- You will need to clear customs and immigration if you are flying through Perth.  Since you're inadmissible, this wouldn't work.
- Gold Coast airport has some complications that may make it impossible.
- Cairns and Sydney are okay, as long as you do not need to stay overnight.
- Adelaide will only work if you depart on the same aircraft from which you arrived, or your airline makes prior arrangements with the airport.

Note also that your citizenship may affect this.  Please read the linked article carefully.

I strongly recommend that you verify this with your airline prior to attempting the flight, otherwise you may be turned back to your point of origin.

Comment: I would really want to check this rather than rely on "you are OK if you don't have to clear customs". In Canada for example you have to abide by visa regulations even if you don't clear customs. That's how they can insist that some people need a visa. I would want to see an explicit statement that the ban did not cover transits.

Comment: You've answered without knowing the persons nationality, which means your answer is potentially incorrect as it will depend on their nationality...

Comment: Based on my reading of that web page I posted above, passengers outside of situations listed above will *not* pass through customs and immigration but instead will remain in a sterile transit lounge.  Please read the references before downvoting my answer.

Comment: Also note that for Australia, re-entry bans are imposed on applications for temporary visas. One can apply for a permanent visa despite having a ban. If the OP needs a transit visa they should check if the transit visa counts as a temporary visa.